# How can I share a large data structure among forked Python processes?

Tags: python, concurrency, fork

I'm creating a 58 GB graph in a Python program, which I then want to process through multiple (Linux) processes.  For that I'm using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` with a `fork` context, passing to each process just an integer associated with the chunk associated with it.

```py
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(mp_context=mp.get_context('fork')) as executor:
        futures = []
        for start in range(0, len(vertices_list), BATCH_SIZE):
            future = executor.submit(process_batch, start)
            futures += [future]
```

The `process_batch` function calculates a metric of the graph's vertices, and returns a small list of results.  Both `vertices_list` and `graph` are global variables.  The `graph` variable is bound to a [C++ Python extension module](https://github.com/dspinellis/fast-cdindex/) that implements the required data structure and calculation.

```py
def process_batch(start):
    results = []
    for v in vertices_list[start:start + BATCH_SIZE]:
        results.append((v, graph.some_metric(v)))
    return results
```

This works fine with small samples, but when I run it on the 58 GB structure, the machine grinds to a halt, with memory getting swapped out to allow the forked processes to bring in more memory in ¼ MB chunks.  (Using *strace(1)* I saw a few such *mmap(2)* calls.)  I  saw two comments ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095876/multiprocessing-fork-vs-spawn#comment124419772_66113051) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-multiprocessing#comment14269453_5550156)) indicating that on Python *fork(2)* actually means copy on access, because just accessing an object will change its ref-count.  This seems consistent with the behavior I'm observing: the forked processes probably attempting to create their own private copy of the data structure.

So my question is: does Python offer a way to share an arbitrary data structure among forked Python processes?  I know about [multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) and the [corresponding facilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), but these concern the built-in `Array` and `Value` types.

Comment: Do you even have 58 GB + Overhead of RAM available to Python? Can't you split your problem / data structure into smaller sub problems that can then be worked on individually, similar to a map-reduce!?

Comment: Yes, the program runs fine as a single process.  The computer has 96 GB of RAM.  But I don't have access to many more such computers to run separate processes on them, so I'm trying to use its multiple cores.

Comment: One possible way to do this is to pickle the graph data structure and then send it to each of the forked processes using a message passing library such as ZeroMQ. The processes can then unpickle the graph and process it without needing to create their own private copies.

Comment: @PrenVen: To unpickle the graph and process it they would need to create their own private copies.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the code in C++ using simply `for_each(execution::par_unseq,`. The program came out at 209 lines against Python's 136 and is 50 times faster than an older unoptimized Python version.