# python multi threading is taking time as multiple of each task execution, how we can parallelise it?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to utilise all cores of my system using python thread pool, but I am not able to parallelise the execution. I executed below code with and without thread pool, the time it took is more or less exactly same.

Though threads are started in parallel, due to python GIL, looks like only one at a time is executing and not all the cores are getting used.

we want to use this code to run ml models but unable to use multiprocessing as multiprocessing copying the dictionary and models which leads to memory limitation.

System conf: 8 core and 32Gb ram.

Any other option to increase CPU utilisation ?

```
import concurrent.futures
import time, os, math
import threading
import multiprocessing


def current_milli_time():
    return round(time.time() * 1000)


def get_cube(num):
    counter = round(1e7)
    print("Counter::::Start: " + str(x) + ", Thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
    [math.exp(i) * math.sinh(i) for i in [1] * counter]


    print("Cube: {}" .format(num * num * num))
    print("Counter::::End: " + str(x) + ", Thread: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
    return num * num * num


def worker(num):
        print("Worker thread started and thread is: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
        print(get_cube(num))
        print("Worker thread completed and thread is: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))


start_time = current_milli_time()


print("Start Time: {}".format(start_time))
print('Number of CPUs in the system: {}'.format(os.cpu_count()))


pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6)


for x in [10,5,3,2,1]:
        print("before submit------------------->"+str(x))
        pool.submit(worker, x)
        #worker(x)
        print("after submit------------------->"+str(x))


#pool.submit(worker(10))
#pool.submit(worker(5))
#pool.submit(worker(3))


pool.shutdown(wait=True)


print("Main thread continuing to run")


end_time = current_milli_time()


print("Time taken : {}".format((end_time - start_time)/1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use multithreading in python if you want to parallelize resource-demanding operations. Multithreading may be suited when you wait for someone's response or when your computer is not in charge of the time-consuming task.

If you want to parallelize computing operations, you must use multiprocessing instead. However, there is a huge difference between multithreading and multiprocessing since processes communicate using the local network or files while threads are able to share memory (so its more convenient and faster).

When using multiprocessing it is also better to be aware of the method used to create the process (fork/spawn, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095876/multiprocessing-fork-vs-spawn)).

In your case you can use a multiprocessing pool instead of a ThreadPoolExecutor as such:

```py
with multiprocessing.Pool(6) as p:
    p.map(worker, [10, 5, 3, 2, 1])
```

Also, you may want to use the [mpire python package](https://github.com/sybrenjansen/mpire) which make some things easier for you.

Comment: You say, "... threads are able to use shared memory ...".  But *shared memory* is an actual term that most people understand to mean memory that can be shared across *processes*. You probably meant to say that threads share the same memory (and therefore do not require *shared memory*). So processes communicate using many things *including* shared memory.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for your comment, I edited my post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As ftorre pointed out, in order to utilize all cores, you need multiprocessing, or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. Here is a template:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import contextlib
import datetime
import logging
import random
import time

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(processName)-20s | %(funcName)-18s | %(message)s",
)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def report_duration():
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    logging.debug("Start time: %s", start_time)
    yield
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    logging.debug("End time: %s", end_time)
    duration = end_time - start_time
    logging.debug("Duration: %d seconds", duration.total_seconds())


def get_cube(number):
    # Simulate some intensive calculation
    delay = random.randint(1, 5)
    time.sleep(delay)

    result = number * number * number
    return result


def worker(number):
    logging.debug("Work on %r", number)
    result = get_cube(number)
    logging.debug("Done, input=%r, output=%r", number, result)
    return result


def main():
    """Entry"""
    input_list = list(range(1, 11))
    with report_duration():
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(worker, input_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
2024-02-02 16:01:57,624 | DEBUG    | MainProcess          | report_duration    | Start time: 2024-02-02 16:01:57.624796
2024-02-02 16:01:57,690 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-2       | worker             | Work on 1
2024-02-02 16:01:57,698 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-1       | worker             | Work on 2
2024-02-02 16:01:57,700 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-6       | worker             | Work on 3
2024-02-02 16:01:57,700 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-3       | worker             | Work on 4
2024-02-02 16:01:57,701 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-4       | worker             | Work on 5
2024-02-02 16:01:57,708 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-5       | worker             | Work on 6
2024-02-02 16:01:57,710 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-7       | worker             | Work on 7
2024-02-02 16:01:57,710 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-8       | worker             | Work on 8
2024-02-02 16:01:59,703 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-1       | worker             | Done, input=2, output=8
2024-02-02 16:01:59,704 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-1       | worker             | Work on 9
2024-02-02 16:01:59,706 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-6       | worker             | Done, input=3, output=27
2024-02-02 16:01:59,708 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-6       | worker             | Work on 10
2024-02-02 16:01:59,715 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-8       | worker             | Done, input=8, output=512
2024-02-02 16:02:00,696 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-2       | worker             | Done, input=1, output=1
2024-02-02 16:02:00,706 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-4       | worker             | Done, input=5, output=125
2024-02-02 16:02:01,709 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-1       | worker             | Done, input=9, output=729
2024-02-02 16:02:01,709 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-6       | worker             | Done, input=10, output=1000
2024-02-02 16:02:01,714 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-5       | worker             | Done, input=6, output=216
2024-02-02 16:02:01,715 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-7       | worker             | Done, input=7, output=343
2024-02-02 16:02:02,705 | DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-3       | worker             | Done, input=4, output=64
2024-02-02 16:02:02,737 | DEBUG    | MainProcess          | report_duration    | End time: 2024-02-02 16:02:02.737088
2024-02-02 16:02:02,737 | DEBUG    | MainProcess          | report_duration    | Duration: 5 seconds
```

Notes

- when dealing with multithreading or multiprocessing, I prefer to use the `logging` library because it is thread-safe, unlike `print`
- I configured the logging to show the process' name, along with the function name, which makes it easy to look at the output and learn
- Note that my system has 8 cores and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` takes advantage of all of them: see the names SpawnProcess-1 to SpawnProcess-8
- Because there are more inputs (10 in this case) than cores, some of the process are reused, see SpawnProcess-1 and SpawnProcess-6
- The `datetime` library is my prefer way to calculate duration. In this case, I have a context manager called `report_duration` which will record the start- and end times and calculate the duration.
- If you care about the results from `worker()`, the `.map()` return these in the same order as the input.
- Look at the duration: Although each time `get_cube()` is called, it incurs 1 to 5 second delay, the total duration for 10 input is about 5 seconds total.